# Using properties of SKSpriteNode for subclass

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, subclass

this is more of a general question about subclasses and inheritance within Swift 4.

In Apple's developer guide, a subclass ("anySubclass") of a custom class ("anySuperclass") can directly access/inherit the parent's properties, e.g.:

anySubclass.anyProperty = xyz (anyProperty was only defined within the Superclass)

**To my question:**

I'm currently working on my first game using SpriteKit and wanted to create subclasses of SKSpriteNode, one of which should be clBackGround.

If I just define it as a subclass of SKSpriteNode, i.e.

```
class clBackGround:SKSpriteNode {
}
```

I would think that I could simply use all properties associated with SKSpriteNode just like this:

```
var bg1 = clBackGround()

bg1.size = ...
.
.
.
```

This does not seem to be working however. So my questions is:

Do I need to initialize all the properties of SKSpriteNode I want to use within clBackGround (using a designated initializer)? How can I then assign an image to an instance of this subclass?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but, generally, if you create a subclass of an object, you don't need to do anything special to access the superclass's properties.  They'll be initialized in the usual fashion.

However, you DO have to ensure that the superclass's initializers get called in a proper manner if you have your own initializers for your subclass.

In the case of a subclass of SKSpriteNode, if you define your own initializer for the subclass, that initializer will need to call the designated superclass initializer, which passes in the texture, color, and size to use for the sprite:

```
init(enemyType:String) {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "enemy_\(enemyType)")
    let color = UIColor.black
    let size = texture.size()
    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed help. One question on what you wrote, would you not need to add the override command to the initializer? (To override the superclass' has default values set for those properties)

Comment: You'd only need to do that if it matches the signature of a function in the superclass.  In other words, if you wanted just init(), then yes, you'd need to override the init() function in the superclass.  But if you have something like init(enemyType:String, withHealth:Int) which doesn't exist in the superclass, there's nothing to override - it's a new function that's not overriding a similarly-named function in the superclass.

Comment: Sure.  If this was helpful, be sure to accept the answer so others can find it.

Comment: Done. Actually I had two follow-up questions on this: (1) how can I set other properties of SKSpriteNode within the subclass itself (as they will stay constant)? (2)  what if I want to add new, custom properties within the subclass. For example I added "var rank: Int = 0" above the initializer within the subclass. when i create an instance of that subclass and call instance.rank it throws an error "rank is not a member of subclass"

Comment: 1)  You can always set properties of SKSpriteNode from the subclass by assigning them after you call super.init().  Or inside the init call, if it's something that is passed into the init method of the superclass.  2)  You should be able to do that.  The problem you're encountering is probably that the calling code thinks it's a SKSpriteNode and not your subclass, but it's hard to say without seeing some code.